# How to edit and save one element of a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to to edit one item of my CSV file and then save the file. Let's say I have a CSV file that reads:

```
A,B,C,D
1,Today,3,4
5,Tomorrow,7,8
```

and I when I do something to the program, I want it to alter the CSV file such that it reads:

```
A,B,C,D
1,Yesterday,3,4
5,Tomorrow,7,8
```

I've tried two approaches:

First, I tried using `pandas.csv_read` to open the file in memory, alter it by using `iloc`, and then save the CSV file using `csv.writer`. Predictably, this resulted in the format of the CSV file being drastically altered (a seemingly arbitrary number of spaces between adjacent entries in a row). This meant that subsequent attempts to edit the CSV file would fail.
Example:

```
A B         C D
1 Yesterday 3 4
5 Tomorrow  7 8
```

The second attempt was similar to the first in that I opened the CSV file and edited it, but I then converted it into a string before using `csv.writer`. The issue with this method is that it saves all of the entries in one row in the CSV file, and I cannot figure out how to tell the program to start a new row.
Example:

```
A,B,C,D,1,Yesterday,3,4,5,Tomorrow,7,8
```

Is there a proper way to edit one entry in a particular row of a CSV file in python?

Comment: You should show us the code that generates the output. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for why

Comment: Hi. Is the entry you want to edit unique? (in the sense that it does not matter in which column of your CSV it is located).I'm thinking you can use some streaming approach to this. Like sed or something similar.

Comment: `df.to_csv()` will save the file in default comma separated format. Did you change the separator?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Leonel, it is unique in the sense that I'll always be editing column "B", but that column could be A or D or whatever (I'm not sure if I'm answering your question?)
MYGz, I will certainly try that. I did change the separator, but I can change it back to ','.

Comment: @MYGz, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.